# all buildscript {} blocks must appear before any plugins {} blocks in the script :8 ~ Android Studio

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-studio, kotlin

I am creating an application using Java and connecting the database to Firebase. I am getting this error in the build file. Please help me to solve this error.
I can't understand the error message please explain me to solve it.
Error

```
Build file 'D:\MyWeb\build.gradle' line: 7

Could not compile build file 'D:\MyWeb\build.gradle'.
> startup failed:
  build file 'D:\MyWeb\build.gradle': 7: all buildscript {} blocks must appear before any plugins {} blocks in the script


build.grable(My Web)
```

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '8.0.2' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '8.0.2' apply false
}

buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()  // Google's Maven repository
        mavenCentral()  // Maven Central repository
    }
    dependencies {// Add the dependency for the Google services Gradle plugin
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.15'
    }
}
allprojects {
    repositories {// Make sure that you have the following two repositories
        google()  // Google's Maven repository
        mavenCentral()  // Maven Central repository
    }
}
```

build.gradle (:app)

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '8.0.2' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '8.0.2' apply false
}

buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()  // Google's Maven repository
        mavenCentral()  // Maven Central repository
    }
    dependencies {// Add the dependency for the Google services Gradle plugin
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.15'
    }
}
allprojects {
    repositories {// Make sure that you have the following two repositories
        google()  // Google's Maven repository
        mavenCentral()  // Maven Central repository
    }
}
```

I'm trying to connect my Android Studio project to Firebase, but I get an error with the build.gradle. Not sure how to fix it.

Comment: Did you even read the error message?

Answer (score 2):

Simply remove the buildscript{} block and add it on top of plugins{} block, Like this:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()  // Google's Maven repository
        mavenCentral()  // Maven Central repository
    }
    dependencies {// Add the dependency for the Google services Gradle plugin
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.15'
    }
}

plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '8.0.2' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '8.0.2' apply false
}

allprojects {
    repositories {// Make sure that you have the following two repositories
        google()  // Google's Maven repository
        mavenCentral()  // Maven Central repository
    }
}
```

Always remember that buildscript{} block should be on top of plugins{} block.

Comment: the news projects in A.S. they come with only plugins